# VB.NET combobox displays System.Data.DataRowView with Access Database

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I am using the following code. While run the combo box displays System.Data.DataRowView rather than the Item name from Database

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        Dim fillcon As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\tcs.accdb")

        Dim asql As String = ("SELECT ItemName FROM Items ORDER BY ItemName")
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(asql, fillcon)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds)
        ComboBox1.ValueMember = "ItemName"
        ComboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("ERROR : " & ex.Message.ToString)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the [.DisplayMember](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to one of your fields that you are querying.

Comment: When you set the DataSource for the combobox you basically took all the DataRows and added them. Now since a DataRow can contain multiple fields, it is added as an object of type DataRowView. You need to specify one of the fields in that query to be displayed. In your case you've only asked for a single field in your query but the object doesn't know this so you still need to tell it what column in your query you want to display. `Combobox1.DisplayMember="ItemPrice"` needs to be added to your code.

Comment: But I want another filed of the Database to be displayed in the comboBox like Combobox1.DisplayMember="ItemName"

Comment: That's fine, but you must add the column in your SELECT statement as you are only pulling in ItemPrice in your current code you've posted.

Comment: Here is what I think you're ultimately going to want as an end result. Add the ItemName to your select statement and put the DisplayMember = "ItemName" and the ValueMember = "ItemPrice" this way you have access to the price of an item when you select a name in the combobox. You can get the price associated with it using the .SelectedValue property

Comment: This is like a Restaurant system project. When I choose the Items from the Combobox(Retrieves from Access Database). The txtUnitPrice automatically changes its prices according to the database.

Comment: With the method I just described, you only have to query the database to get everything you need at once. Both are stored in the combobox so you don't need to re-query with each selection to get the price.

Comment: While i use both ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "ItemName"
ComboBox1.ValueMember = "ItemPrice"
  i got the following error https://flic.kr/p/BZQqVN

Comment: Your query needs to be `"SELECT ItemName, ItemPrice FROM Items ORDER BY ItemName"` From there you need the following lines: `Combobox1.DisplayMember = "ItemName"` then you need `Combobox1.ValueMember = "ItemPrice"` Note that you will not see price as it's not visible. But you can get the item price by using Combobox1.SelectedValue.ToString. However, with the binding ItemPrice to a textbox like you originally had should show the price when you select an item in the combobox.